# Print multidimensional array's end-values with full keys path

Tags: php, arrays

I have multidimensional array, for example:

```
$input = [
    'a' => [
        'b' => 'c', 
        'd' => 'e',
        'f' => [
            'g' => 'h'
        ],
    ],
    'i' => 'j',
    'k' => [
        'l' => 'm'
    ],
];
```

I need to print all non-array values with the full key path to it. Like this:

```
a > b > c
a > d > e
a > f > g > h
i > j
k > l > m
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Result of what? What are you trying to achieve? Can you please edit your answer and add more code, preferably some we can also test?

Comment: I've clarified my post, review please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a recursive function to traverse the levels of your array. This should give you your desired results:

```
function list_paths($input) {
    $paths = array();
    foreach ($input as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            foreach (list_paths($v) as $path) {
                $paths[] = $k . " > " . $path;
            }
        }
        else {
            $paths[] = $k . " > " . $v;
        }
    }
    return $paths;
}
print_r(list_paths($input));
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => a > b > c
    [1] => a > d > e
    [2] => a > f > g > h
    [3] => i > j
    [4] => k > l > m 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/6Oiqk)

Comment: Thank you very much! Thats it. Could not do the "path" part.