# Recursively loop throught multidemensional array and keep track of parent array

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

That's a short version of the array I'm working with:

```
Array
(
[orders] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 123
                [email] => somemail@mail.com
                [line_items] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 456
                                )
                    )
            )
        )
)
```

I'd like to loop through it and echo out every $key => $value pair but keep track of the "parent" array.
When using this function:

```
function recursive($array, $level = 0){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            recursive($value, $level + 1);
        } else{
            echo $key . ": " . $value, "\n";  
        }
    }
}
```

i get:

```
id: 123
email: somemail@mail.com
id: 456
```

and I would like to keep the parent array in front of the values so that i know which `id` is echoed out.

```
orders_0_id: 123
orders_0_email: somemail@mail.com
line_items_0_id: 456
```

Updated working solution:

```
function recursive($array, $level = -1,array $parentKey = []){
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $newKey = array_merge($parentKey, [$key]);
    if(is_array($value)){
        recursive($value, $level + 1, $newKey);
    } else{
      $parent = implode('_', $newKey);
      echo $parent . ": " . $value, "\n";  
    }
}
```

}

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807200/print-multidimensional-arrays-end-values-with-full-keys-path) - [working demo](https://3v4l.org/AJAtL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, but it might be too much information.

Given this array:

```php
$data = [
    'orders' => [
        [
            'id' => 123,
            'email' => 'text@example.com',
            'line_items' => [
                [
                    'id' => 356,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

You can keep track of the parent key in an array:

```php
function dumper(array $array, array $parentKey = [])
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $newKey = array_merge($parentKey, [$key]);
        if (is_array($value)) {
            dumper($value, $newKey);
        } else {
            $s = implode('_', $newKey) . ": " . $value . "\n";
            echo $s . PHP_EOL;

        }

    }
}

dumper($data);
```

This produces:

```php
orders_0_id: 123

orders_0_email: text@example.com

orders_0_line_items_0_id: 356
```

Comment: thx. I took some parts of your answer and posted it to my code. I updated my question with the working solution.